# Steering assist is misaligned

Tags: honda, civic

I have a 2006 Civic Hybrid with about 225kkm on it. The only real problem I've had is that the steering assist motor keeps pulling to the left. They can fix this in seconds and charge me $150 for an "alignment", but then over a period of about six months it happens again and again.

Yes, it is 100% entirely in the assist system, the car has been repeatedly checked for everything else and there's no actual mechanical problem, the tires show zero sign of uneven wear, and most notably, if you are parked and turn off the ignition, you can see the steering wheel suddenly "straighten out" to the right.

So... is there anything *I* can do about this? I'm getting tired of paying for a guy to push a button.

Comment: What exactly does this “alignment” entail? Are they doing a sensor relearn?

Comment: Yes they tell it to relearn center. However, they charge me for.an alignment.